# Spring Data Mongo: Compare Two Dates in the Same Document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

A brief overview of the document I am working with:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class BreachBrand {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @CreatedDate
  @Field("created_date")
  @DiffIgnore
  private Instant createdDate;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Field("last_modified_date")
  @DiffIgnore
  private Instant lastModifiedDate;
}
```

What I am trying to do is compare the lastModifiedDate to the createdDate. So I created a criteria object like so:

```
criteria.add(Criteria.where("last_modified_date").gt("ISODate('created_date')"));
```

I've also tried:

```
criteria.add(Criteria.where("last_modified_date").gt("created_date"));
```

which is then used in the match operation of an Aggregation object. Using the first criteria code snippet, the aggregation looks like this:

```
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__", "pipeline" : [{ "$lookup" : { "from" : "brands", "localField" : "brand_dfp_id", "foreignField" : "dfp_id", "as" : "brand"}}, { "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "last_modified_date" : { "$gt" : "ISODate('created_date')"}}]}}, { "$sort" : { "date" : -1}}, { "$skip" : 0}, { "$limit" : 25}], "allowDiskUse" : true, "collation" : { "locale" : "en", "strength" : 1}}
```

The mongoTemplate object executes the aggregate method w/o error but no records are returned.

I'm suspecting that the gt(Object o) method is expecting an object that is an actual value to use to compare against. All is good when I use an actual date:

```
criteria.add(Criteria.where("last_modified_date").gt(Instant.parse("2019-05-18T17:07:25.333+00:00")));
```

As an interesting aside the following works in mongoshell:

```
db.breaches.find({$where: "this.last_modified_date>this.created_date"}).pretty();
```

And the following works in Compass (but the export to language button will not display the output):

```
/**
 * $match operation 
 */
{
  last_modified_date: {$gt: ISODate('created_date')}
}
```

EDIT:
It appears I need to use a projection to determine if last_modified_date is greater than created date. I got this to work in compass:

```
[{
    $project: {
        greater: {
            $gt: [
                '$last_modified_date',
                '$created_date'
            ]
        },
        doc: '$$ROOT'
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        greater: true
    }
}]
```

I'm having issues moving that into a projection though:

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project("last_modified_date", "created_date").andExpression("$gt", "$last_modified_date", "$created_date").as("greater");
```

I've also tried this:

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project("last_modified_date", "created_date").andExpression("$gt", Arrays.asList("$last_modified_date", "$created_date")).as("greater");
```

Results in an exception when creating the aggregation:

```
Aggregation aggregation =  newAggregation(
lookup("brands", "brand_dfp_id", "dfp_id", "brand"),
projectionOperation,
matchOperation, //Criteria.where("greater").is(true)
sortOperation,
skipOperation,
limitOperation
)
.withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder()
.allowDiskUse(true)
.collation(Collation.of("en").strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.primary())).build());
```

exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'date'!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.SortOperation.toDocument(SortOperation.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation.toPipelineStages(AggregationOperation.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationRenderer.toDocument(AggregationOperationRenderer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationPipeline.toDocuments(AggregationPipeline.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toPipeline(Aggregation.java:705)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.AggregationUtil.createPipeline(AggregationUtil.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doAggregate(MongoTemplate.java:2118)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:2093)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1992)
```

Comment: You can also use the `$expr` operator within the `$match` stage to compare two fields within the same document - and avoid using `$project` + `$match`.

Comment: @prasad_ I got this approach to work, thank you! I had already tried using $expr once but was doing it wrong. Again, thank you!